# Make Scala compiler stop on first error

Tags: scala

I'd like `scalac` to stop the build on the first error. I've been finding a large number of cases where all subsequent errors are caused directly by the first error, so those subsequent errors are just noise and I'd like to remove that.

Is there an option that I can pass to `scalac` to do this?

If it matters, I'm working on a Play Framework project and building via the Activator (using `~run` to automatically rebuild on changes).

Comment: The problem with this is that if there are two separate errors, you're going to have to build it twice to discover them both.  With long build times, that would not be fun.

Comment: Good point. Although I usually have to build multiple times, anyway, since it's often unclear if the errors after the first are real errors or just cascading effects of the first error.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In sbt this is done quite simply by seting the `maxErrors` setting:

```
maxErrors := 1
```

If you want to set it temporarily for your current session, just do:

```
set maxErrors := 1
```

just before doing `~run`

Comment: This is useful when using sbt but not applicable to direct use of scalac. Any idea how sbt implements this?

Comment: This is true, but it applies to OP's quesiton, given that he **does** use sbt (through the *Activator*). Unfortunaely, it seems that sbt implements this feature purely by having its logger ignore the errors reported by `scalac` once it reached `maxErrors`. So yes indeed you're out of luck if you're using `scalac` directly (but in this case you can use `-XPrompt` as suggested by ntalbs in the answer he deleted).

Comment: As far as I can tell `scalac` does not have an option which would allow this.

Comment: Added this Key to `build.sbt`:  
    ```scala
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    commonSettings
    ,name := ...
    ,libraryDependencies += ...
    ...
    ,maxErrors := whatever amount of errors pleased you
    ...
  ) 
    ```
Works like a charm .  
Closest [reference](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Tasks.html#Missing+values) in the sbt docs .

Comment: scalac 2.12 has `-Xmaxerrs` and `-Xmaxwarns`.

Comment: @som-snytt: That's great, you should post a new answer then.